# How to Merge Rows in Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i am using Crystal Report Version=10.2 , Visual Studio 2008 and displaying the result of stored procedure in crystal report 
my stored procedure returns output as shown below

[image]

but i want to display in report as  shown below

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use group to hide the common value. HTH

Comment: Try this:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10275456/how-to-do-grouping-in-crystal-report-in-cnet.aspx

HTH.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use group for `Com No.` and put the details of Sub - Status and Date in the details section.

Initially it will look like

```
---------------------------------------------
Com No.  |  Desc.    |   Status  |  Date     |
---------------------------------------------
   1     |   a       |
                     |    sub    | 01/01/2012|
                     |    ack    | 02/01/2012|
                     |    inv    | 03/01/2012|
---------------------------------------------
```

Then:

Use the section expert and set overlay on for the group. So you will get the following:

```
---------------------------------------------
Com No.  |  Desc.    |   Status  |  Date     |
---------------------------------------------
   1     |   a       |    sub    | 01/01/2012|
                     |    ack    | 02/01/2012|
                     |    inv    | 03/01/2012|
---------------------------------------------
```

Putting the value of `Com No` and `Desc` in the middle of the box is tricky. If you know the number of rows in the detail section, you can increase the height of the group header in proportion can give you the result:

```
---------------------------------------------
Com No.  |  Desc.    |   Status  |  Date     |
---------------------------------------------
                     |    sub    | 01/01/2012|
   1     |   a       |    ack    | 02/01/2012|
                     |    inv    | 03/01/2012|
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: i am getting data in marathi from procedure,but report displaying it as / any idea for displaying data in marathi

Comment: Is it a web app or win app? In web app, you need to enable language support on the browser. Also look at the output setting for utf-8.

Comment: i was using Unicode For Marathi Language in my WebApp so Just By Changing the Font to Unicode solved my problem

Comment: thank you, i have the similar problem and i spend one week to find the solution until i see your answer its very brilliant

Comment: Can you detail a bit about the last step?

Comment: @andySF The last step is to align the content to the centre vertically. This is tricky. If youknow the vertical space (no of rows) in the detail section, then you can put it correctly. In the example, there are three rows in the detail section. So putting the header section with a space of one line works. 

I am not aware if there is an advancement to it in later versions of the Crystal report. I have not used since many years now.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use a cross-tab to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

**First step**

1. create running total
2. select com no
3. summary will be count
4. for each record.
5. reset select on change group
6. save the running total as rtotal

**2nd step**

1. create a formula name will be total
2. add this "ceiling(count(Status,ComNo)/2)" this formula will find the middle point.
3. save the formula

**Third step**

1. create another formula name will be isSupress
2. add this "if(#rtotal=total) then false else true"
3. save the formula

**4th step**

1. select com no.
2. format object->suppress->formula
3. just place issupress formula
4. save the suppress formula.

Run the report.