# Merge cells after suppressing if duplicate

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have this records in crystal report:

[image]

I tried suppress if duplicate and this is the result:

[image]

What I want to be the result is like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to make it like that? I tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529255/5218582 but the result is just like the second pic. Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement is certainly possible.

1. Easiest way is to use the cross tab to get this functionality.
2. There is one more way bit lenghty one but you can use a sub report to display the ID and country and in main report you display name and you need to play a bit with the lines to correclt view as per the requirement but in this case aswell you will get the name at the top not at the middle.